# Kendo grid format decimal

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've created a kendo grid based on a html table. I want the number in the grid to display only 2 decimals, but I can not figure out how to do this. Please help. See my code below.

```
<table id='test'>
    <tr>
        <th data-field='field1' data-type='number' data-template='#= kendo.toString(field1, "n2") #'>
        ColumnHeader
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.2579</td>
    </tr>
</table>        

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#plStatsGrid").kendoGrid({});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic scripting error.  Your script is looking for table with id `plStatsGrid`, but your table has id `test`.  [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dudv3wmx/1/).

```
<table id='plStatsGrid'>
    <tr>
        <th data-field='field1' data-type='number' data-template='#= kendo.toString(field1, "n2") #'>
        ColumnHeader
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.2579</td>
    </tr>
</table>        

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#plStatsGrid").kendoGrid({});
    });
</script>
```